# How to get typing status of the other side with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, typing

I've seens this in various places,

during chat,I can see whether the other party is typing or not .

How do implement this most easily?

Comment: "How do implement this most easily?" You can't - this is one of the trickiest things to do with HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use AJAX.

When user A first presses a key, you can tell the server that he started typing.
5 seconds after the last keypress (call `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout` in `onkeyup`), tell the server that he stopped.

Then, on user B's side, use polling or comet to ask the server what it received from user A.

Answer (score 0):

The chat client code sends something back to the server when it sees a keyboard event. The server then either pushes information to other clients, or else the other clients poll the server every once in a while.

Comment: Making a separate request on each keypress would be extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is can be solved using XMPP/BOSH way. Check for [Strophe.js](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe) -- very good xmpp library.
Or you can do this with AJAX and server polling... I'd recommend XMPP...

Comment: Have you ever digg into how `Strophe.js` implements **Comet**?

Comment: No, i didn't. And i'm sure its a server technology - long-help request a-la *Comet*. So here we need to talk about "how jabber server (BOSH) implements it".

Comment: Actually,I don't think it's a pure server technology.

Comment: Yes, its not. Client must understand that this request must be long-held. Personally i prefer xmpp way. But Comet is good too. You can choose - each of them can help you with all kind of chat notifications. But keep in mind thad jabber servers already support it (via presence/iq/etc stanzas) and you can chat with people who uses desctop clients like Adium/Miranda. With Comet you can't do this.